# How to save a string that is given from the form in the html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, riot-games-api

I'm following this [tutorial](http://organicrails.github.io/2015-07-20-Riftodds/).

This tutorial was made with older versions of Ruby/Rails and HAML that I didn't learn yet, so I'm trying to do the exact same app but working.

Here is what the app should do, the user puts in the view :

- Their name on League of Legends (a game if any of you don't know
  this) => called p1
- The name of a friend on League of Legends => called p2
- The name of their champion => called c1
- The name of the champion of a friend => called c2

Here is the code :

```
<%= form_for :player, url: players_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :p1, "First Summoner's Name "  %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.text_field :p1 %>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <%= f.label :p2, "Second Summoner's Name" %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.text_field :p2 %>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <%= f.label :c1, "Summoner One's Champion" %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.text_field :c1 %>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <%= f.label :c2, "Summoner Two's Champion" %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.text_field :c2 %>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then I use the Riot API. The point is to calculate the winrate of each player with their respective champion.
So far everything is done and works, but I can't manage to get the champs ID. In order to get this data I use this method

```
def self.get_champion_id(champ_name)
    api = RiotApi.new
    champs = api.get_champion
    champs["data"]["id"]

end
```

My problem is that, to get the id, I need to give the method, the name of the champion (named c1 and c2 previously) but I have no idea on how to achieve that, it should look like

```
def self.get_champion_id(champ_name)
    api = RiotApi.new
    champs = api.get_champion
    champs["data"]["CHAMPION_NAME"]["id"]

end
```

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/Zepri/lolapp2) if you want to check the code, you can't do the api calls without a key

Thanks for any advice !

Comment: `champs["data"][champ_name]["id"]` ???

Comment: what is the structure of champs? some more infos needed

Comment: champs returns this hash -> [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wKpmWabC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes than it should be

```
champs["data"][champ_name]["id"]
```